# check login credential in codeigniter framework for a login system

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I'm new to programming.Need some help in codeigniter login system...This is my code
this is the controller function....how to check name and password is correct credential

```
function login(){
    if($this->input->post("submit")){
        $values=array(
            "name"=>$this->input->post("name"),
            "password"=>$this->input->post("password")
            );

    }
    $this->load->view("view_login");

}
```

Comment: Sidenote: Why are you using an older version of CI? They're up to 3 now. https://www.codeigniter.com/ - check for errors also.